# Array not returning correct value

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to apply text to whether the events inside my event group have spaces available or are sold out.

My loop looks at each event in the event group and returns whether they are sold out or available for each specific event. My issue is that it's just returning the same value for both events rather than looking at each specific event so it is returning the wrong value.

It adds these to an array and implodes each one out, but the second value is always wrong. Any ideas?

Even if the second event has hit it's capacity value, it still shows as available

```
public function getAreEventsAvailableStringMultiple() {
    $availability = null;
    foreach ($this->events as $event) {
        $availability[] = $this->getAreEventsAvailable() ? 'Spaces still available' : 'Sold Out';
    }
    return implode(' <br/> ', $availability);
}
```

Other function

```
 public function getAreEventsAvailable() {
        foreach ($this->events as $event) {
            if ($event->getRemainingCapacity() > 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: calling same function on each iteration `$this->getAreEventsAvailable()` ? I think you are missing param `$this->getAreEventsAvailable($event)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over `$this->events` (which is probably an array of event objects), but checking availability for `$this`, meaning the current object.

If `$this->events` is array of objects, then you should do this:

```
   foreach ($this->events as $event) {
       $availability[] = $event->getAreEventsAvailable() ? 'Spaces still available' : 'Sold Out';
   }
```

Assuming that your Event object has `getAreEventsAvailable()` method.

If `$this->getAreEventsAvailable()` returns availability for all the events, there is no need for the `foreach` loop, just assign the result to `$availability`:

```
$availability = $this->getAreEventsAvailable();
```

EDIT:
Your `getAreEventsAvailable()` should look like this:

```
public function getAreEventsAvailable() {
    $availability = [];

    foreach ($this->events as $event) {
        if ($event->getRemainingCapacity() > 0) {
            $availability[] = true;
        } else {
            $availability[] = false;
        }
    }

    return $availability;
}
```

and then in your `getAreEventsAvailableStringMultiple()` function:

```
public function getAreEventsAvailableStringMultiple() {
    $availability = [];

    foreach ($this->getAreEventsAvailable() as $eventAvailable) {
        $availability[] = $eventAvailable ? 'Spaces still available' : 'Sold Out';
    }
    return implode(' <br/> ', $availability);
}
```

It is not the most ellegant solution, but it should work.

Comment: I have updated my question with the other function. Only returns one result with your suggestion.

Comment: `return` means "exit the function and return this value". So after the first execution of your loop it returns a value and quits the function. I updated my answer.